# Is changing the src of an iframe (different domain than host page) with javascript considered cross site scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page with an iframe that has no source on page load and just uses hardcoded html like this:

```
<iframe id="theframe" src="">
<html>
    <body>
         <form name="theform" action="http://domainB.com/new" method="POST">
         <input type="text" />
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

The form is then submitted in jQuery using

```
$('#theform').submit();
```

This causes the source of the iframe to change from nothing (same domain) to domainB.com where the form data is sent and stored.

I then delay 1s to show success msg and then wish to set the frame back to it's original contents by changing the source back to nothing (same domain) and appending the original form, like this:

```
    $('iframe').attr('src', '');
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').empty();
    $('iframe').contents().find('body').append('<form name="theform" action="http://domainB.com/new" method="POST"><input type="text" /></form>');
```

However it's not working... Is this cross site scripting even though I'm not trying to access the inner content of domainB, I'm just setting the src of the iframe back to domainA??

If so, is there anyway to set the src once it's been changed to a different domain?

(As I wrote the last sentence I realized I could just delete the iframe and replace it with a new one, I think?, but I'd still like to know if changing the source is considered cross site and thats why it's not working?)

Comment: May I ask why you're half the way to submitting that via ajax (you even use a js library that should support that.. is that jQuery?) and you're using that awful-looking iframe solution? [btw, you can't send requests from js to external domains, so you should proxy the submit through a page on the same server that serves the first page..]

Comment: I am using an iframe because I need to submit the page without reloading the main page, I am aware ajax does this but I can't use ajax because of the separate domains. (cross-site scripting) Hence, I submit the form inside an iframe and only that refreshes, not the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just returns `true` or `false`.

```
$('iframe').attr('src') == '';
```

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', '');
```

Comment: You can't set the return value of a function.

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. However, when I just set the attr there is no error, but as soon as it tries to set the content back to the form it gives the cross site error still.